# SVM Training: prediction do not give expected result for 1 column feature

Tags: matlab, svm

I only have observation with one feature (column) only

- The  positive observation have values with 83% below 1 (so 17% above 1). Number of positive observation is  **8K** only
- Negative observation have values with 74% above 1 (so 16% below 1).Number of negative observation is **105K**

I feed those observation into matlab function **fitcsvm**:

```
svmStruct = fitcsvm(features,Y,'Standardize',true, 'Prior','uniform','KernelFunction','linear','KernelScale','auto','Verbose',1,'IterationLimit',1000000);
```

I expecting when I run **predict** to give me 1 for positives feature because it trained for most positive features are less than 1 and most negative features are greater than one. However when run  **predict**

```
 [label,score,cost]= predict(svmStruct, postive_features) ;
```

all label are zero, which is not an expected answer. I dont know why? does SVM works when there is only 1 features?

Notice, also I got message **"SVM optimization did not converge to the required tolerance."** after running **fitcsvm**